# Why does a C comment like /* */ need '<'?

Tags: c++, c, doxygen

My teams C-code guidelines write that it'd be better to place a '<' in a comment like shown below:

```
#define MAX_PACK_ITEM_NUM 50  /**<  max number of item */
```

I wonder, what is the real use of this '<' ?

Comment: Erm, as an arrow? It's a comment, so there's no one here that's going to be able to answer that.

Comment: What is the answer from your team?

Comment: Why do people want to close this? It's a perfectly valid question!

Comment: maybe a hint to a documentation generator..

Comment: @Michael It is not. It is either too localized or not constructive. Why there is a need for `<` he should ask the creator of the code guidelines in his company.

Comment: I'm sure few people learned something from this question, and as for whether it can be considered localized, meta has a pretty good answer: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4818/what-questions-should-be-closed-with-reason-too-localized

Comment: @VJo: If it were a company-specific convention I'd agree, but as it turns out it's about doxygen -- and there are currently 413 questions tagged `[doxygen]`.

Comment: Ok, the modified question fits the FAQ

Comment: Off topic, but do your guidelines also recommend `#define ...` instead of `const int` ...?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

It's a way for `doxygen` to generate documentation for members of a file/struct/union/class/enum. By using that marker, you can put comments after each member, leading to less clutter. You can read more about it [here](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/docblocks.html).

Answer (score 50):

As others have replied, this is probably a comment that is meant for doxygen. When parsing comments, doxygen have some special rules:

- An ordinary comment starting with `/*` is *ignored* by doxygen.
- A comment starting with `/**` is treated as documentation of the *next item after the comment* in the source code.
- A comment starting with `/**<` is treated as documentation of the item *immediately before* the comment in the source code.

Documentation is mostly placed above the documented item, e.g. a function. But in some cases such as a `#define` it makes sense to put the documentation at the end of the line instead and in that case the `/**<` marker is needed.

Answer (score 17):

It is a [doxygen syntax](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/docblocks.html) for commenting members after declaration/definition.

Answer (score 11):

I assume your team uses some automated documentation tool which looks for `/**<`; e.g. [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/docblocks.html#cppblock).

Comment: Doxygen for example uses these angle brackets to describe members etc